# How do I pass a variable to border style property in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component which is being passed in a colour as a prop that I wish to use as a border colour on a table. Not sure how I go about it. Tried the following which was predictably wrong but I wasn't sure how I would get this to work:

```js
 <th class="text-left" :style="'border-left: 10px solid colour;'">Statement</th>
```

In the above example, 'colour' is the name of the prop being passed in. How do I set a border colour dynamically, please?

Comment: Did you try to use a template string there? I. e. :style="`border-left: 10px solid ${colour};`"

Comment: Yeah, think I got it all wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you bind your style, it expects an object.

This is an object: `{}`. You start with curly braces you can see it in the documentation too https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

```
:style="{ 'border-left': '10px solid ' + colour }"
```

or with literals:

```
:style="{ 'border-left': `10px solid ${colour}` }"
```

You dont need to put everything inside the HTML markup, you can also put it into the `data`:

```
data() {
   return {
      styling: {
         'border-left:': `10px solid ${this.colour}`
      }
   }
}

:style="styling"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [string template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to do such a thing.
Should look something like this.
`` :style = "{ `border-left: 10px solid ${colour}` }" ``